# Maps Folium Python

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, folium

```py
import folium 
import pandas as pd

df_bedarf = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx.csv', sep = ";")
df_bedarf.head()

df_locations = df_bedarf[["Latitude", "Longitude"]]
location_list = df_locations.values.tolist()
location_list_size= len(location_list)

map_points = folium.Map(location = [47.57087, 13.43828], zoom_start = 7)

for point in range(0, location_list_size):
    folium.circle(
        location = location_list[point],
        popup=df_locations["suburb"][point] + ": " + df_locations["Sort"][point],
        radius = str(df_locations["t/a"][point]*100)
        color="#17cbef",
        fill=True,
        opacity =0.8,
        fill_color="#17cbef,
        stroke = True, 
        weight = 1.0,
    ).add_to(map_points)
    
map_points
```

This is the head():

```
    Unnamed: 0  Suburb  Sort    t/a     Latitude    Longitude
0   0   Wien    CC  2272    48.201900   16.370000
1   1   Graz    LD  426     47.079675   15.420325
2   2   Feldbach    LD  248     46.952187   15.888309
3   3   Zerlach     RE  2041    46.944865   15.650902
4   4   Gnas    SM  1488    46.874198   15.826138
```

I get a syntax error???

Where is my error?

Comment: There is a typo, instead of `        fill_color="#17cbef,` it should be `        fill_color="#17cbef",`.

Comment: For future reference, the syntax error that Python gives you will tell you exactly where and what the problem is. You can find how to read those errors [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#syntax-errors).

Comment: Thanks. It says the sytanx error is within line 29 color....

Comment: The typo in fill_color was not the problem.
Tahnks for the docu

Comment: Case is closed. had some major syntax errors: comma after radius = ........
the next one is instead of df_locations use df_bedarf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error was probably that the latitude and longitude of the location information was not in list format. It is easier to handle the data frame with df.itertools(), so I modified the code. Also, the size of the circle is referenced by adding a new column as appropriate, so please fix this. The color and transparency of the circles have also been modified to make them easier to locate.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
  Suburb  Sort    t/a     Latitude    Longitude
0   Wien    CC  2272    48.201900   16.370000
1   Graz    LD  426     47.079675   15.420325
2   Feldbach    LD  248     46.952187   15.888309
3   Zerlach     RE  2041    46.944865   15.650902
4   Gnas    SM  1488    46.874198   15.826138
'''

df_locations = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df_locations['points'] = np.random.randint(100, 500, (5,))

import folium 

map_points = folium.Map(location=[47.210565, 15.8311348], zoom_start=7)

# for i in range(len(df_locations)):
for idx, row in df_locations.iterrows():
    folium.Circle(
        location=[row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
        popup=row["Suburb"] + ": " + str(row["Sort"]),
        radius = row['points']*100,
        color="#dc143c",
        fill=True,
        opacity=1.0,
        fill_color="#dc143c",
        stroke=True,
        weight=1.0,
    ).add_to(map_points)

map_points
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really helpful and informative. Maybe you could also hepl me with another problem described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892669/heatmap-on-folium-with-pandas

I know that my code is not appropriate to have wat I want, but since I am quite a beginner, I dont know where to start looking for a solution