# Heatmap on Folium with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, gradient, heatmap, folium

I have following syntax which does not deliver what I am trying to do:

```
df_bedarf = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/xxxxx/xxxxxx.csv', sep = ";")
df_bedarf.head()

df_locations = df_bedarf[["Latitude", "Longitude"]]
location_list = df_locations.values.tolist()
location_list_size= len(location_list)

## Creating a Points Map

map_points = folium.Map(location = [47.57087, 13.43828], zoom_start = 7)

for point in range(0, location_list_size):
    folium.Circle(
        location = location_list[point],
        popup=df_bedarf["Suburb"][point] + ": " + df_bedarf["Sort"][point],
        radius = 10000, blur = 10000,
        min_opacity =0.3,
        gradient = {.3: "yellow", .6: "orange", 1: "red"},
        max_zoom =1,
    ).add_to(map_points)
    
map_points
```

I want that with gradient the colour gets more red, the higer t/a is.

The header of the CSV is following:

```
Unnamed: 0  Suburb  Sort    t/a     Latitude    Longitude
0   0   Wien    CC  2272    48.201900   16.370000
1   1   Graz    LD  426     47.079675   15.420325
2   2   Feldbach    LD  248     46.952187   15.888309
3   3   Zerlach     RE  2041    46.944865   15.650902
4   4   Gnas    SM  1488    46.874198   15.826138
```

instead I only get blue circles on my map.
What do I have to change to get circles with changing colors depending on the amount (t/a)

Thanks in advance and regards

---

it should look somehow like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change the color for each marker is to use the bin classification function on a numeric column and set the desired color name for that numeric value. If you want to increase the number of colors, increase the bins and labels.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Suburb Sort t/a Latitude Longitude
0 Wien CC 2272 48.201900 16.370000
1 Graz LD 426 47.079675 15.420325
2 Feldbach LD 248 46.952187 15.888309
3 Zerlach RE 2041 46.944865 15.650902
4 Gnas SM 1488 46.874198 15.826138
'''

df_locations = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
colors = pd.cut(df_locations['t/a'], bins=4, labels=['hotpink', 'tomato', 'red', 'crimson'])
colors = colors.to_list()

df_locations

    Suburb  Sort    t/a     Latitude    Longitude   marker_color
0   Wien    CC  2272    48.201900   16.370000   crimson
1   Graz    LD  426     47.079675   15.420325   hotpink
2   Feldbach    LD  248     46.952187   15.888309   hotpink
3   Zerlach     RE  2041    46.944865   15.650902   crimson
4   Gnas    SM  1488    46.874198   15.826138   red

map_points = folium.Map(location = [47.57087, 13.43828], zoom_start = 7)

for idx, row in df_locations.iterrows():
    folium.Circle(
        location = [row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
        popup=row["Suburb"] + ": " + row["Sort"],
        radius = 10000,
        # blur = 10000,
        color=colors[idx],
        fill_color=colors[idx],
        # min_opacity=0.3,
        # max_zoom=1,
    ).add_to(map_points)
    
map_points
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the size of the circle to be a t/a value instead of constant, you can do so by modifying the radius setting. `radius=row['t/a']`

Comment: Thanks for your tip. anyhow I think this is not a solution for my problem since I dont like to add colors manually for each line in my csv file... I will send a photo so u can maybe imagine better Lieferadresse:

Comment: One way to do this is to add a column to the dataframe, but the same is true if you specify a list for the color. The image is a combination of markers and circles. Giving the expected image after the fact will only confuse the respondent. If there is something you expect, you should add it to the question.

Comment: Changed the format from writing to the columns of the data frame as commented to a list format. Please check.